# Blender 4.02 Where is the Node Search input box

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, interface, compositing-nodes

I have blender 4.02 and now when I am in the Node Editor, GN editor or Compositor and choose 'Add' (as in add node) I am NOT offered a search box, which is generally what I use.  I no longer have this search box and have to hunt the node menus.  How do I fix this?

Comment: What if you do Shift + A and then type a letter? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, thx, I always used the Add -> Search.  I guess I'll have to adjust.

Comment: If you use the add menu, you also just need to type a letter after you click ADD

Comment: You should watch live streams by Cartesian Caramel on Youtube. He's complaining about this change several times in each video. Then you would have been aware of that. Actually I find it more convenient to start typing right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 4.0 you can search in every menu by typing <kbd>Space</kbd> while menu is opened.

[image]

But the Add (Add object, Add modifier, Add node) menu is not requiring to press <kbd>Space</kbd> first. Just start typing.

This feature is introduced in 4.0, and you can find it in [release notes](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/4-0/#search)

Answer (score 2):

Click 'Add' and just type something to search.